# Is it possible to restrict copy paste to a page using apache shiro? If yes then how can I achieve it?

Tags: shiro

I want to restrict copy paste of text on page using apache shiro for a web application. 
Does shiro has those capabilities. If yes then how can it be achieved? 
Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I can't. Shiro is a serverside framework. What you are looking for is some sort of javascript library.